# Replicate just some documents in couchDB using curl

Tags: regex, erlang, couchdb, database-replication

The docs say I can partially replicate one database to another using the selector syntax. And that it works the same as for the `_find` command. So I've been testing with `_find` first.

I know the `_id` of the documents I want to replicate, but there are enough of them that I want to use a regex.

I was able to get this command to work:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d "{\"selector\":{\"_id\":\"doc-A\"}}" http://admin:PW@127.0.0.1:5984/mydb/_find
```

But not my regex attempt; I would like to get "doc-A", "doc-B", "doc-XYZ", ... as well as "other-this", "other-that", and so on.

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d "{\"selector\":{\"_id\":{\"$regex\":\"^(doc-|other-)\"}}}" http://admin:PW@127.0.0.1:5984/mydb/_find
```

The error I get is nasty-looking:

```
{"error":"badmatch","reason":"{error,{{mango_error,mango_util,{invalid_field_name,<<\"_id.\">>}},
  nil,
  [{mango_util,check_non_empty,2,
               [{file,\"src/mango_util.erl\"},{line,399}]},
   {mango_util,parse_field,1,[{file,\"src/mango_util.erl\"},{line,382}]},
   {mango_doc,get_field,3,[{file,\"src/mango_doc.erl\"},{line,375}]},
   {mango_selector,match,3,[{file,\"src/mango_selector.erl\"},{line,572}]},
   {mango_cursor_view,view_cb,2,
                      [{file,\"src/mango_cursor_view.erl\"},{line,257}]},
   {couch_mrview,map_fold,3,[{file,\"src/couch_mrview.erl\"},{line,491}]},
   {couch_bt_engine,include_reductions,4,
                    [{file,\"src/couch_bt_engine.erl\"},{line,1170}]},
   {couch_bt_engine,skip_deleted,4,
                    [{file,\"src/couch_bt_engine.erl\"},{line,1165}]}]}}","ref":2902755775}
```

It seems to be saying I cannot use `_id` to filter on?

I had a brief look at Erlang regex support, and it seems like it would cover what I want to achieve here?

I'm running couchdb 3.1.1, on Ubuntu and Mint.

Taking a step back, as I am not selecting by the document content, just by `_id`, which should be easier, I wonder if there is an easier way to accomplish a partial replication?

I need to script this, so ideally want it done with a curl command. However if it is the only way to get the job done, I can use a node+nano script, or install another tool.

Comment: What shell are you using? That trailing period (`_id.`) looks out of place.

Comment: @RamblinRose I'm using bash. But the working command defines `_id` in exactly the same way, so I think the shell/curl side of things is not to blame (?). I also noticed that `.` and wondered about it.

Comment: FWIW in git-bash, this works on my 3.1.1 CouchDB: `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{""selector"":{""_id"":{""$regex"": ""^(doc-|other-)""}}}" http://name:pwd@127.0.0.1:5984/stack/_find`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a hint from @RamblinRose in the comments, it turns out this was due to not escaping the `$` in the `\"$regex\"`.  (All examples here are using bash-escaping.)

Changing to `\"\$regex\"` worked. But even simpler was to just wrap the JSON with single quotes instead of double quotes, and then neither the `"` nor the `$` need escaping:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"selector":{"_id":{"$regex":"^(doc-|other-)"}}}' \
  http://admin:PW@127.0.0.1:5984/mydb/_find
```

And to answer my main question, here is how to set up a filtering replication with `curl`:

```
 export ADMINDB='http://admin:PASSWORD@127.0.0.1:5984'
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"source": "'${ADMINDB}'/db_one", "target": "'${ADMINDB}'/db_two", "selector":{"_id":{"$regex":"^(doc-|other-)"}} "create_target": false, "continuous": false}' \
  ${ADMINDB}/_replicator
```

Note: the leading space on the export, so the password does not enter bash history.

Note: the single quotes around `${ADMINDB}` so variable insertion works while still being able to use single quotes, and not mess around with backslashes.

Note: The rev numbers carry over from db_one to db_two, but I end up with conflicts on the documents that already exists.

Much more serious, if I then edit e.g. "doc-A" in db_two, e.g. take it from rev-72 to rev-74, and then run the replicate command again, it does not get replaced. Not even a conflict. It stays on rev-74 with the new data. If I delete the documents in db_two, then run the replicate command, they stay deleted in db_two.

So, in summary, this is the CouchDB Way. If you just want to copy some documents from one DB to another, forcefully replacing them if they already exist, that is not the CouchDB Way, and you cannot do it (with `_replicate`).